# Cognitive Image search for Visually Similar Products fails with 404 Post error

Tags: c#, bing, azure-cognitive-services, windows-10-desktop

Can anyone explain any possible reasons why I am getting 404 responses to the
         `var postResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(BingApiUrl, content);`
call in the code at the end of this post.

[image]

This code was copied from the GitHub code found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/intelligence-SimilarProducts/Services/BingImageSearchService.cs).

I am trying to search for additional product images that match a Samsung Galaxy mobile phone image that I stored in my project assets.

I know my subscription key works for image searches with a text search key. Now I am trying to find images similar to an image stored in memory whose bytes are included as the body of my POST request.

Do I need to have searched Bing for the Samsung image by name first before asking for similar images, or can I initiate a search purely on the basis of an image in memory?

```
    private static readonly string BingApiUrl = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?modulesRequested=VisuallySimilarProducts&mkt=en-au&form=BCSPRD";

    private async void btnImgSearchByDrawing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Wait, 1);

        RandomAccessStreamReference streamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Samsung-Galaxy-S7-32GB-3-xl.jpg"));
        IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType streamWithContent = await streamRef.OpenReadAsync();
        Stream stream = streamWithContent.AsStreamForRead();

        await GetSimilarProductImagesAsync(stream);

        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Arrow, 1);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of visually similar products from an image stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to an image.</param>
    /// <returns>List of visually similar images.</returns>
    public async Task<IList<ImageResult>> GetSimilarProductImagesAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            var strContent = new StreamContent(stream);

            strContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { FileName = "Samsung-Galaxy-S7-32GB-3-xl.jpg" };

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(strContent);

            var postResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(BingApiUrl, content);
            var text = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BingImageResponse>(text);

            return response?.VisuallySimilarProducts?.Select(i => new ImageResult
            {
                HostPageDisplayUrl = i.HostPageDisplayUrl,
                HostPageUrl = i.HostPageUrl,
                Name = i.Name,
                ThumbnailUrl = i.ThumbnailUrl,
                WebSearchUrl = i.WebSearchUrl
            })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked is using Bing Search v5. Yours is using v7 and that only supports issuing GET requests. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-images-api-v7-reference). Also note that the call has to have a mandatory `q` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Now I'm confused as the v7 docs you referenced says this under imgUrl"The URL of an image that you want to get insights of. Use this parameter as an alternative to using the insightsToken parameter to specify the image. You may also specify the image by placing the binary of the image in the body of a POST request. If you use the binary option, see the Content-Type header."

Comment: Yeah the documentations are odd. That parameter is for another endpoint. Yours is search so it doesn't apply. You should read each query param on that page and see if it applies to /search.

Comment: Thanks again...So can you tell me is there any way to use the api to search for images similar to one already stored in my app and supplied in binary form to the api. I just want to mimic the Bing/Images webpage where you upload an image stored only my PC and have the api return similar images from the web.  Robert

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that. Robert

Answer (score 0):

You can also get similar images from the image url itself using the following call:

GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/details?imgurl=Your_IMAGE_URL&mkt=en-us&modules=similarimages" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"

This should work with v5 as well.